# Convert ARM template in Azure to Gallery Template in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-workflow-automation

I would like to know how to convert ARM template in Azure to Gallery Template in Azure .I am not able to save the ARM template but able to save the Gallery Template .

Answer (score 0):

- Azure Resource Manager Templates to be converted as Template specs to store in Gallery.
- As per this [**Microsoft Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-spec-convert#manually-convert-through-portal) here are the steps to convert template manually through Azure portal.

> 1. Open the  [Templates (preview)](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.Gallery%2Fmyareas%2Fgalleryitems)  in the portal.
> 2. Select the template to migrate.
> 3. Select  **View Template**.
> 4. Copy the template content.
> 5. In the portal search bar, search for  **Template specs**. Select that option.
> 6. Select  **Create template spec**.
> 7. Provide values for the name, subscription, resource group, location, and version.
> 8. Select  **Next: Edit template**.
> 9. For the contents of the template, paste the template you copied from the template gallery.
> 10. Select  **Review + Create**.
> 11. After validation successfully completes, select  **Create**.

- And here is the **[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/quickstart-create-template-specs?tabs=azure-powershell)** for creating Template Spec from ARM.